# What about the measurable sets that are not countable unions?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

$S=\left\{0,1,2\right\}, X=S^{\mathbb{Z}}$, let $S$ be equipped with the discrete topology and $X$ with the product topology which I call $\tau$. The set $\mathcal{C}$ containing the so-called cylinder sets
$$
C_t[a_0,...,a_m]:=\left\{x=(x_i)_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}\in X: x_t=a_0,x_{t+1}=a_1,...,x_{t+m}=a_m\right\}
$$
with $a_i\in S$ for all $0\leq i\leq m$, form a base of the product topology $\tau$ on $X$. Let $\mathcal{E}$ denote the product-$\sigma$-algebra on $X$.

> > Am I right that I do have the special situation here that
> >     $$
> > \tau=\mathcal{B}(X)=\mathcal{E}=\sigma(\mathcal{C})?
> > $$

If yes, I am wondering about the following. Let $E\in\mathcal{E}$ be any measurable set. Then, if the identities are right, it is $E\in\tau$ and $E$ can be written as an union of cylindersets, $E=\bigcup_{i\in I}C_{t_i}[a_0,...,a_m]$. Now, $I$ can be *any index set*.

What, if $I$ is not finite or countable? Is such an union in a $\sigma$-algebra at all? If $\mu$ is a measure on $\mathcal{E}$,does $\mu(E)$ makes any sense then? I guess yes, since here such an union is in $\tau$. But what is with for example $\sigma$-additivity?

Maybe I just have an error in my thoughts...

Answer (score 0):

> $ \tau=\mathcal{B}(X)=\mathcal{E}=\sigma(\mathcal{C})? $

I understood by $\mathcal{B}(X)$ the family of all Borel subsets of the topological space $(X,\tau)$, that is the $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(\tau)$ generated by $\tau$ and by $\mathcal E=\sigma(\mathcal{C})$ the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal C$. Since $\mathcal C\subset\tau$, $\sigma(\mathcal{C})\subset \mathcal{B}(X)$. The opposite inclusion holds because the space $X$ is second-countable, so each element of $\tau$ is a union of countably many cylinder sets. But, of course, $\tau$ is strictly smaller than $\mathcal{B}(X)$ because the there exist Borel sets in $X$ which are not open (for instance, one-point sets).